# Sendind and receving response on serial port

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I need to send the command #010 to the serial port COM4 and it will response with a value, I try it with an external software and all it's Ok:

[image]

I've used this code to get the response from serial:

```
comPort = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[2];
comPort.setNumDataBits(8);
comPort.setNumStopBits(1);
comPort.setParity(SerialPort.NO_PARITY);
comPort.setBaudRate(9600);
comPort.openPort();
OutputStream outputStream = comPort.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(("#010").getBytes());
InputStream inputStream = comPort.getInputStream();
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];
System.out.println(inputStream.read());
String result  = new String(readBuffer);
```

But never receive the response, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `outputStream.write(("#010\n").getBytes());`

Comment: No, the same problem!

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the correct COM port - can you list them all out?